# Standard SQL in bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run queries in standard mode via command line. I'm using recently version of this bigquery-2.0.17.

firstly I tried to use bq query command:

```
bq  query --use_legacy_sql=False  "SELECT string_col FROM `source_name`"
```

And get exception

> FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'use_legacy_sql'

After, I've run in shell mode

```
project_name> query --use_legacy_sql=False "SELECT string_col FROM `source_name`"
```

And get:

> float() argument must be a string or a number

Could you advise me, how can I run query in command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands you are running are all correct. The only thing I do differently is I read the queries from a file so I don't have problems with my bash trying to interpret the ` sign, like so:

```
cat query.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=False
```

(You won't have this issue in the bq shell interpreter).

Supposing your queries are all correct and following the [Standard syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) (you can also run a simple query like `"select [1, 2]"` to see if it works, if it does, then maybe your `source_name` has some issue going on), the only thing that comes to mind is maybe if you try to [reinstall gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) and even update it (currently we are at bq version 2.0.24), as this seems to be more related to environment rather than command syntax.

Comment: Your comment seems to imply you have gotten `--use_legacy_sql=False to` work in the bq shell interpreter, is that correct?  I haven't been able to do that either with a command line flag or with a flag setting in .bigqueryrc. It always says `FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'use_legacy_sql'`

Comment: @yokeho I recommend asking in SO showing what you are trying to run along with the error message. Not sure why it's not working for you, maybe there's something missing somewhere else in the command you're running

Answer (score 0):

Need to use gcloud installation instead of alone bq.
Thanks